# CSS code works if put in style="", fails if put in external css file

Tags: html, css

I have some html in this format:

```
<ul id="foo">
    <li class="bar"><a href="#">Reports</a>
      <span>
        <a href="#" class="fooLink">First Report</a>
        <a href="#" class="fooLink">Second Report</a>
     </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Essentially, I want the 'reports' link in the menu to expand when clicked, and display the links below it, padded to the side, so it looks like this:

```
Reports
   First report
   Second report
```

This is my css code:

```css
.fooLink
{
    padding-left: 20%; 
    padding-top: 0px;
    display:block;
}
```

However this doesn't work. If I examine the links in firebug, I see that the `display:block;` line is blocked. However if I do this:

```
<a href="#" 
   style="padding-left:20%; padding-top:0px; display:block;">Second Report</a>
```

Then it works as I want it. Why doesn't it work if i put it in the css class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying CSS via the `style` attribute always* trumps styles provided via stylesheets, due to specificity, as @Kirean mentions.

That means that when you move your CSS to an external stylesheet, it has to compete with other defined styles.

You can make your style selector more specific than the other definition, but you have to know what you are competing with.

`.fooLink` is more specific than `a`

`a.fooLink` is more specific than `.fooLink`

`span a.fooLink` is more specific still, etc, etc

According to the W3C specification, your `.fooLink` selector can be trumped by any selector with: more class selectors (`.foo .fooLink`), the same number of class selectors and more type selectors (`.foo a`), or any selector with an ID (`#foo *`), assuming the selector applies to the same element.

Now, the caveat (as implied by the asterisk above) is that you can override this behavior using `!important`.  `!important` trumps other defined style attributes.  If there are multiple `!important` declarations, they are resolved according to standard specificity rules.

So, the best solution is to make your style as specific as possible, and edit other styles which may be conflicting.

If, however, those other definitions are out of your control (site-wide CSS stylesheets or something like that), use `!important`:

```
.fooLink
{
    padding-left: 20%; 
    padding-top: 0px;
    display:block !important;
}
```

Comment: caveat: use important sparingly :)  As Jeff says, its good to use it when other css is out of your control, but beyond that, I dont suggest it.

Comment: @Kirean: Absolutely.  OP's question was low enough on detail that they might have had a problem where this would be the solution.  I just wanted to put it out there.  I avoid using `!important` if possible, otherwise you end up with headaches when you want something to be *really* important. :)

Answer (score 2):

check your other CSS declarations for conflicting styles, paying close attention to [Specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity).  Firebug should give you what CSS is actually applied, and where it's coming from.

http://jsfiddle.net/PEbRQ/

seems to work (though its an embedded CSS block, not an external file.

Comment: It works for me as well if i put the code in `style=....` but if i just do `class=...` and put the css code in the class, then it doesn't work.

Comment: I want to be able to put it in a class so I won't have to put in the inline css for dozens of links

Comment: As Kirean pointed out, the specificity of your CSS class declaration is not as high as some other CSS that is already on the page for the same element.  You need to be more specific, i.e. #foo li span a.fooLink

Comment: I understand and agree. Generally classes are the better choice.  That JSFiddle has it as a class declaration in an embedded `<style>` block, not inline, and it works just fine.  So check with firebug for conflicting selector declarations.  Its possible another CSS definition is overwriting your style.

Comment: @Steve thanks, following your syntax it now works. If you'd like to post an answer on how to be specific (i.e the syntax) I'll accept the answer

Comment: @ClickUpvote that guarantees that there is *some other css definition* that is overwriting your style because of a higher specificity.  You need to inspect your CSS file for this and clean it up.

Comment: Actually, I would prefer not to make that an answer... :)  Kirean's answer describes exactly what I said and he deserves the credit.  I just gave an example of what he meant.