# background image works in "style" but not inside the css file

Tags: html, css

I`m want to make a sprite image, this is my css:

```
img.Bayern
{
   background: url(Images/Popular.png) no-repeat;
    width: 14px; height: 11px;background-position: 0 0;
}
```

and my html:

```
<img class="Bayern"  />
```

But the image is not displayed, however when i place the css code inside style="" , it works properly.

I checked this similar question: [CSS code works if put in style="", fails if put in external css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423024/css-code-works-if-put-in-style-fails-if-put-in-external-css-file)

and did put the img inside:

```
<span id="nav-flag">
   <img class="Bayern"  />
   </span>

 #nav-flag img.Bayern { ...same css...}
```

But it still doesnt work. Also i changed the relative path to: ../Images, ./Images, into '...'.
Does anybody knows what im doing wrong??

Comment: sounds like you have a relative path problem, either when you link in your CSS file or when you request the image via the CSS. Why are you applying a background image to an `img` element anyway?

Comment: Try putting the full URLpath of the image

Comment: Show us the code where you include the `CSS file`.

Comment: Are html file and css file in one folder on one level? What is files structure?

Comment: The problem is with the path for sure, because all the css code works "width: 14px; height: 11px;background-position: 0 0;"  except the "background: url(Images/Popular.png) no-repeat;"

Comment: I'm also thinking of a potential specificity issue.

Comment: or you linked the css in the html in a wrong way. Can you write your html in the question? Also create a jsfiddle if possible.

Comment: Please think about the img element, from the Documentation: "The src attribute must be present". Maybe you want to use some other element like div.

Comment: or if you have the webpage hosted on your server you also can give the link of your website directly

Comment: yes also what @StefanNeubert said is surely right

Comment: you shouldn't use an img tag and set its background through css, you should use a div instead, then you can give it a class and style it normally. Else you use an image but don't use the background property. they are 2 different things. You should have in mind what you want to achieve, then choose. Probably you want to use a div though

Comment: Okk just let me try all of the suggestions

Comment: Ok im gona try to answer to all of the questons, when i replace my image path with this uploaded image http://www.tishbi.eu/img/shopping_cart.png the css works. I`ve tryed to replace the <img> with a <div> then it doesnt work at all and i dont know why, even that i tried that on http://jsfiddle.net/Yx8tT/ .     So i also added a src="" to the img but that doesn`t seemed to make a problem. Im creating a web site its not online yet.   So should i keep trying to make it work with a <div> tag or sholud i just try to change something with the path?

Comment: I put a <img> tag because of this example http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sprites_img    but i will keep trying to make it work with a div tag

Answer (score 3):

You're using a relative URL on background image `Images/Popular.png` (i.e. the URL did not start with a leading slash `/` nor the scheme like `http://`).

When using such a relative URL in `style` attribute, it's relative to the request URL of the webpage as appears in the browser's address bar. So if it's for example http://example.com/page.html, then the image is expected to be in http://example.com/Images/Popular.png.

When using such a relative URL in a CSS file, it's relative to the request URL of the CSS file itself. So if it's for example http://example.com/css/style.css, then the image is expected to be in http://example.com/css/Images/Popular.png.

You need to make sure that the image file is exactly there where the specified URL expects it to be (so, put it in same folder as the CSS file), or you need to fix the URL accordingly so that it's properly relative to the request URL (so, use `/Images/Popular.png` instead).

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, it's quite strange to specify a CSS background image on an `<img>` element. You normally specify that on some block element like `<div>`.